# What causes you to become Unbeatable in PvP?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Today I was "Unbeatable" in PvP for the first time, accompanied by the normal "An ally is unbeatable!" announcement.  Upon Googling it I found that this is awarded when you get 4 medals in a single spawn (without dying).  However, I had 7-8 medals at the time and hadn't died all match, so the information I found elsewhere would appear to be wrong.

Does anyone know exactly what causes you to become Unbeatable?

Comment: I was guarding a turret in Civil War most of the time, so most of my medals were for defense; perhaps it requires different "types" of medals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It used to be 4 medals, due to the fact there are more medals now  since 1.2 it has been changed to 8 medals without dying.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Halfwarr's answer, you get Invincible and Immortal for 14 and 18 medals since your last death, respectively.